# Get value from html-tag

Tags: scala, gatling

I'm new to Gatling.
I wonder how I could get the value from HTML tag  in Gatling and make .check that HTML-tag "title" contains "Test"?

```
val scn = scenario("Scenario")
    .exec(http("MyTest")
        .get("/myPage/")
        .headers(headers_0)
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

You really should go through the [official tutorials](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/tutorials/advanced/#step-3-use-dynamic-data-with-feeders-and-checks), as how to use CSS selectors checks is covered there.

Note: this will only work if HTML content is rendered server-side.

Comment: I uncommented <logger name="io.gatling.http.engine.response" level="TRACE" /> there I can see my title. So I then tried with .check(substring("Test").find(1).exists) But the response says "Found nothing"

Comment: It really feels like you're trying to skip reading the documentation, which you shouldn't. Please have a look at https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/check/#find. find(n) is 0 based, so find(1) is trying to capture the SECOND occurrence.

Comment: oh I'm sorry thanks